# tput in a cron job does not output bolded text

Tags: linux, cron, tput

I comeback with a very strange behavior

when we run this command on Linux redhat machine

```
echo "$(tput bold)" start write to log  "$(tput sgr0)" >> /tmp/log.txt
```

we get ended **bold text** in `/tmp/log.txt`

```
more /tmp/log.txt
start write to log  <----- BOLD TEXT
```

but when we run it from cron job under /etc/cron.d

```
*/1 * * * * root [[ -f /home/mng_log.sh ]] &&   echo "$(tput bold)" start write to log  "$(tput sgr0)" >> /tmp/log.txt
```

then the text in `/tmp/log.txt` isn't bold

why the cli from cron job not write the bold test ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tput bold` writes the character sequence that is to be used to tell the **current terminal** it is running in to start writing in bold.

It knows the type of the terminal based on the value of the `$TERM` environment variable. That variable is set by terminal emulators or by `getty`.

`tput` queries the `termcap` or `terminfo` databases to know what sequence to use for a given attribute for a given terminal type.

For instance, when running in an `xterm`, where `$TERM` will be something like `xterm` or `xterm-256color`, `tput bold` will write `\e[1m` which is the sequence recognised by `xterm` (and most modern terminal emulators) to start writing in bold. When running in an `hpterm`, it will send `\e&dB` instead.

When a script is running from `cron`, it is not running in a terminal. If you want it to send a sequence to enable the bold attribute, you need to tell it for what terminal that should be, by setting the `$TERM` environment variable.

Maybe something like:

```
export TERM="${TERM-xterm}" # set $TERM to xterm if not set
printf '%s\n' "$(tput bold)start write to log$(tput sgr0)" >> /tmp/log.txt
```

Then your `/tmp/log.txt` will contain the xterm sequence to turn *bold* on. When the content of the file is sent to a xterm terminal emulator, it will be displayed in bold, YMMV for other terminals.

Comment: thank you so much for the great answer , let me check your solution and I will back to you .........

Comment: after testing its not work

Comment: we set it in the script - export TERM="${TERM-xterm}"  , bot still test isnt BOLD -:(

Comment: any other option?

Comment: @yael just use the escapes directly `printf '\033[1m%s\033[m\n' "start write to log"` instead of that `tput` command subst overkill.

Comment: @yael or much better, don't put binary cr^Wescapes in text files, write just `'## start write to log ##'` and then use postprocessing, syntax highlighting or similar when displaying the log.

Comment: @mosvy, another device independent way to mark text in bold is to use the roff-style `t\bte\bex\bxt\bt` approach (recognised by pagers and invisible when sent to terminals). (not that I would recommend it for a log file either).

Comment: Dear Stéphane , see please my answer , it is working when I set it

Comment: @yael;  Stéphane's answer sets TERM only if it's not already set, so you might be running into a situation where you've already set TERM to something that doesn't support the bolding sequence.